# React Redux Firebase File Upload

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-redux, google-cloud-functions, es6-promise

I'm new to react. I'm attempting a file upload to Firebase, and while it's going good, I cannot seem to save the picture url to the pictureUrl state. I'm pulling the url from the promise, and it's working fine, but how do I get the downloadUrl from the promise into the pictureUrl state? Any ideas?

**Data Submission**

```
      handleSubmit(e){
          e.preventDefault();
          console.log(this.state.picture)

          this.props.uploadImage(this.state.picture)

        const article = {
          header: this.state.header,
          tagLine: this.state.tagLine,
          articleType: this.state.articleType,
          system: this.state.system,
          body: this.state.body,
          pictureUrl: ???????
      }

      this.props.saveArticle(article);

      console.log('Data saved!')  

      // Resets the state back to nothing
        this.setState({
          header: '',
          tagLine: '',
          articleType: '',
          system: '',
          body: '',
          pictureUrl: ''
        })
      }
```

**Firebase Call To Upload File**

```
           export function saveArticle(article, file){
                return dispatch => database.push(article);
            }

            export function uploadImage(picture){
                    return dispatch => storage.child('/images/' + picture.name).put(picture).then((snapshot) => {


                        snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL().then(function(downloadURL) { 

                        console.log('File available at: ', downloadURL)
                        })
                    })

                    console.log(picture)

            }
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to put it into state first then you can call that state back. I'm also new to react, I also have a similar problem before. Maybe you should look at this example.

You have to call the variables back.

**For example**

```
render{
return{
<PDF
 file={this.state.pdfUrl}
  />
 }
}
```

https://medium.com/@650egor/react-30-day-challenge-day-4-firebase-photo-upload-delete-f7c59d73ae36

[Loading images from Firebase Realtime Database + Storage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39929187/loading-images-from-firebase-realtime-database-storage?rq=1)